# What CSS selector to modify checkbox label when input is inside label?

Tags: css, checkbox, django-forms

I'm trying to replace the default browser checkbox style, but my input is inside my label.

I'm using Django, and the form output for a CheckboxSelectMultiple field looks like this:

```
<label for="id_field">Field Name</label>
<ul id="id_field">
<li><label for="id_field_0"><input id="id_field_0" name="field" type="checkbox" value="0" /> Field 1 Name</label></li>
<li><label for="id_field_1"><input id="id_field_1" name="field" type="checkbox" value="1" /> Field Name 2</label></li>
</ul>
```

I can still style the label normally, but how do I change the label style when `#id_field_0:checked`? CSS doesn't have any way to go back to the parent object, does it? What selector can I use do accomplish this?

Comment: You cannot (in CSS), because you cannot select an element on the basis of the state of its child. Try to change the markup so that the `label` element appears *after* the associated `input` element (this is more logical, too).

Comment: It is not possible, not for now, it will be implemented(or is already) in `CSS4`. You will have to use `JavaScript` in the mean time.

Comment: To others with this problem: Vitorino Fernandes answer works, or alternatively, you can access the code for individual buttons in Django by looping {{ for selection in form.field }} (insert whatever different html you want here) {{ endfor }}

Comment: Just in case anyone else is looking for the "Vitorino Fernandes answer" mentioned by the comment above, the answer is this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26502163/854076

Comment: Whilst you might not be able to do it directly, it's possible to have a custom checkbox style with the label around the checkbox, but you need extra elements and sibling selectors. Example http://wtfforms.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/vjp9f7L2/8/

used span for styling `checkbox` and `:before` pseudo

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
label {
  display: inline-block;
}
label > input + span {
  cursor: pointer;
}
span {
  display: block;
}
label > span.check {
  background: url('http://cdn.flaticon.com/png/32/24396.png');
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}
label > input {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}
label > input:checked + span:before {
  content: url('http://cdn.flaticon.com/png/32/60731.png');
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input id="" type="checkbox" value="" name="" /> <span class="check"></span>

</label>
<label>
  <input id="" type="checkbox" value="" name="" /> <span class="check"></span>

</label>
<label>
  <input id="" type="checkbox" value="" name="" /> <span class="check"></span>

</label>
```

Comment: Can you have a descriptual text label that is connected to the checkbox with this example?

Answer (score 2):

It´s not posible now, you can try this:

```
<label for="id_field">Field Name</label>
    <ul id="id_field">
    <li>
        <input id="id_field_0" name="field" type="checkbox" value="0">
        <label for="id_field_0">Field 1 Name</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input id="id_field_1" name="field" type="checkbox" value="1"> 
        <label for="id_field_1">Field Name 2</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And then in CSS:

```
label {/* all labels */}
input + label {/* label after input which is the same as "input in label" */}
```

You used attribute `for`, which isn´t necessary when using inputs inside labels, so no additional HTML will be there.

Answer (score 0):

```
<label>
    <input id="num" type="checkbox" value="" name="numbers" /> <span class="check"></span>

</label>
<label>
    <input id="" type="checkbox" value="" name="" /> <span class="check"></span>

</label>
<label>
    <input id="" type="checkbox" value="" name="" /> <span class="check"></span>

</label>
```

Comment: Explaining what you've changed or fixed would make this answer even more useful to future readers!